# Virtualbox: how to add a second disk to a Windows XP Snapshot

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, disk-space

I would like to add a second drive to my windows XP image that was created small (10 Giga).
I've created a 20 Giga `dataHarddisk2.vpi` on the IDE Secondary Master from the control panel but when XP boots up, it just shows the original 10 Giga partition.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with adding a real hard drive in a real machine, you need to go into "disk management" in "computer management" to partition (and format) the drive.